# Android: How to load a YouTube Channel in a WebView?

Tags: android, youtube, webview

I am attempting to create an in-app page that loads a YouTube channel inside a WebView.  I've gotten pretty much everything working except the actual playing of the video.  It's as if inside the WebView, when I tap on the video to play it, the message gets lost.  I do not see a call to shouldOverrideUrlLoading() as I would expect.

Code is:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new webViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("url"));
    }   

    private class webViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.equals("about:blank")) {
                return true;
            }
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The URL that gets loaded is something like: http://www.youtube.com/tinhtevideo for an example.  Am I missing something?  I would exepct that shouldOverridingUrlLoading() would be called with a URL like "vnd.youtube:" but I never see it.

Of course if I load the above URL in the Android browser, everything works fine.

Comment: Hey I am facing the same problem

Did u get any solution for this????

if you know soln for this then please share it

Answer (score 1):

I use a html file, then put a tag in it. 
Something like this.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video}}?autoplay=1" 
        frameborder="0" 
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Then load my whole html into the webview.

```
private String myHtmlData = "";    //myHtmlData is my html file
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
myHtmlData, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
myWebView.loadData(myHtmlData, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

By the way,I put my html file in the asset category of the project.

```
getAssets().open(fileName);
```

Hope it can solve your problem.

Comment: user wants to load the channel and eventually click on a video, not just load one video